# Swift iOS: Detect when a user drags/slides finger over a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a project where I’m adding three UILabels to the view controller’s view. When the user begins moving their finger around the screen, I want to be able to determine when they their finger is moving over any of these UILabels.

I’m assuming a UIPanGestureRecognizer is what I need (for when the user is moving their finger around the screen) but I’m not sure where to add the gesture. (I can add a tap gesture to a UILabel, but this isn’t what I need)

Assuming I add the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the main view, how would I go about accomplishing this?

```
if gesture.state == .changed { 
    // if finger moving over UILabelA… 
    // …do this 
    // else if finger moving over UILabelB… 
    // …do something else 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or by implementing `touchesMoved(...)` - which to use depends on what else you might be doing.

For pan gesture, add the recognizer to the `view` (NOT to the labels):

```
@objc func handlePan(_ g: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if g.state == .changed {
        // get the location of the gesture
        let loc = g.location(in: view)
        // loop through each label to see if its frame contains the gesture point
        theLabels.forEach { v in
            if v.frame.contains(loc) {
                print("Pan Gesture - we're panning over label:", v.text)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

For using touches, no need to add a gesture recognizer:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let t = touches.first {
        // get the location of the touch
        let loc = t.location(in: view)
        // loop through each label to see if its frame contains the touch point
        theLabels.forEach { v in
            if v.frame.contains(loc) {
                print("Touch - we're dragging the touch over label:", v.text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```